# What happens when a .NET console app blocks on Console.ReadLine()?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I had an interesting interview question today. Consider you have the following console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When the Console.ReadLine() line is reached execution is suspended and the program waits for input from the keyboard. How many threads are there at this point and what state are they in, e.g. Running, Suspended, etc. ?

I suppose what the interviewer was after was awareness/understanding of the threads that make up a .NET console app and how they work together to interact with the IO subsystem of the underlying OS.

Comment: As far as the application is concerned, there is only one thread. If the operating system creates additional threads behind-the-scenes, that is an irrelevant implementation detail from the application's perspective.

Comment: And `Console.ReadLine();` only blocks the thread you are executing it in.

Comment: The interviewer probably has some experience with WinDbg debugging, https://www.jayway.com/2011/04/26/getting-started-with-managed-dump-files-using-windbg/ so that he/she can penetrate deeper into the process and threads than you. If you master the tools and tips, such questions won't be a barrier in the future.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no definite number.

Your code is only running on one thread - the main thread. Calling `Console.ReadLine` doesn't create a new thread, it just starts an I/O request and waits for it to be processed - this requires no threads, but since you're using the synchronous API, there's no way to release your thread, so it just blocks. If the interviewer wanted just one number, *this is the number* - it's the only application thread you have, everything else is an implementation detail.

There's a lot of infrastructure threads - the Garbage Collector threads are the main ones, and some of those are created and destroyed all the time.

Finally, there's the threads somewhere in between - most notably, the thread pool. Since you're not using the thread-pool, it will have the default number of threads - unless the configuration says otherwise, this is usually two threads per logical CPU core.

The reality goes even deeper. For example, .NET threads are managed threads, and they may skip between "native" threads at the will of the runtime. However, this is something you never really need to care about unless you're writing your own .NET runtime or an operating system :) Or, doing heavy interop with native code that depends on native thread-affinity (again, not very common).

I suspect the main purpose of the question is to get you talking about how the Windows threading model works, how .NET handles threads and what kinds of threads there are in a typical windows/.NET application. But mainly, to get you to talk :P

Comment: By "skip native threads", do you mean *create*? Is this an idiomatic use of skip that I'm unfamiliar with, or just a typo?

Comment: I see. Yes, "between" would clear things up. Skip, switch, skip/switch, whichever.

Comment: Perhaps he wanted to hear about the GC thread and such - can't be certain. I think he was only talking about managed threads rather than OS threads. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: @alex.tashev Yeah, but note that as far as .NET is concerned, there need not be a garbage collector at all. It's perfectly valid for a .NET implementation to just keep allocating over and over without collecting at all, and such approaches have been used in the past in fact (the "collection" being done when the process exits), though I'm not aware of any existing .NET runtime that does this. It's good to be aware of your runtime reality, but don't rely on it too much - the specification is the only contract there is, everything else is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Luuan, therefore, depending on what your interviewer meant, there is for example VisualStudio threads running in addition to the Main thread. BTW, this thread can be disabled (In VS2015: Project Properties > Debug tab > uncheck Enable the Visual Studio hosting Process)

If you are using Visual Studio, you should be able to see the threads during  debugging.

The running code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world");           
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The Thread Window (In VS2015: Debug -> Windows -> Threads):

[image]

I added a new thread to your example:

The running code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
    new Thread(DoSomethingElse).Start();            
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void DoSomethingElse()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.SpinWait(100);
    }
}
```

The Thread Window:

[image]

Comment: The scenario was that you run the executable from the command line - I forgot to mention that, so I don't think he meant the additional VS threads.